# NUXT | Ошибка 419 CSRF token mismatch при отправке post-запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, http, axios, nuxt.js

Отправляю axios запрос:

```
async login(state, data) {
    console.log('Logggin');
    console.log(data);
    this.$axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', {phone:'88005553535',password:'123456789'},
    {
        header:{
        "Access":'application/json'
    }}).then(data => {
        console.log("Logined");
        console.log(data);
    });
},
```

В ответ мне приходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему возникает эта проблема?
P.S
Можете просить у меня фрагменты кода, просто не знал, что вставить

Answer (score 1):

Это срабатывает CSRF защита Laravel, все POST запросы должны содержать CSRF- токен,который вам надо указать в заголовке запроса(секции Header)

```
headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
```

предварительно в Blade шаблоне в секции `<head>` вставьте следующий код:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

подробнее можно почитать в официальной документации к Laravel (https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/csrf).
Лично я, когда пишу фронтэнд под Laravel, в app.js указываю следующий код:
`let token = document.head.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]'); window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = token.content;`

- теперь каждый axios.post запрос будет отправляться с этим токеном, и отпадает необходимость указывать его при каждом POST запросе.

Comment: Проблема не на Laravel, а на Nuxt непосредственно, я создал пустой проект и запрос пришел как нужно, создал еще один пустой проект - запрос снова выдал ошибку...

Comment: Проблема именно со стороны бэкэнда(laravel), еще раз повторюсь все пост запросы требуют CSRF токен, и на первом скрине как раз указана ошибка, которая дословно переводится как "несоответствие токена csrf"..посмотрите внимательнее на путь, кто кинул исключение? Laravel..Работаю со стеком laravel\vuejs около 5 лет, 419 статус это CSRF, попробуйте использовать тот код что я вам привел, в welcome.blade.php(или какой у вас корневой шаблон отдается) в секции `<head>` укажите мета тег, а в корневом vuejs установите глобальные настройки axios как я показал выше и все пройдет

Comment: попробуйте отправить гетом,(предварительно сменив метод в роутере laravel) запрос пройдет на ура, а любой пост, ждет токен.

Comment: не помогло ничего, каким-то образом заметил что, если запрос отправляется с порта 3000, то ошибка выдается, при любом другом порте все работает как нужно

Comment: а зачем Вам 3000 порт вообще нужен? у Laravel очень не плохой свой встроенный сервер, вызывается командой php artisan serve в корне проекта, веб сервер будет работать на 8000 порту..Либо более подробно обрисуйте свою архитектуру, или все же попробуйте советы данные вам выше